# hardlinks on ntfs with windows

Tags: windows, ntfs, hardlink

How can I create hardlinks for a file on an NTFS partition using Windows?

NTFS can obviously handle hardlinks, since creating them with NTFS-3g works – the links even work in Windows. Is this the only way to create hardlinks on NTFS?

Answer (score 4):

`cmd` includes the [`mklink` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(WS.10).aspx) which can create hardlinks:

> Creates a symbolic link.
>
> `MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target`
>
> > `/D`      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file symbolic link.
> >
> > **`/H`      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.**
> >
> > `/J`      Creates a Directory Junction.
> >
> > `Link`    specifies the new symbolic link name.
> >
> > `Target`  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link refers to.

Furthermore, the excellent [Far Manager](http://farmanager.com) has support for creating them (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>).

There are also [a number of shell extensions](http://www.bing.com/search?q=hardlink+windows+shell+extension&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC) that allow for doing so.

Comment: wow, even softlinks. didn't know they even existed in windows. or is it those `.lnk` files? good answer, i didn't know that command

Comment: .lnk files are shortcut files -- a shell-level item.  Symlinks are an NTFS-level link.

Comment: i tried this today, cmd.exe does not seem to recognize `mklink`. OS was windows xp

Comment: @knittl: I was assuming a *recent* version of Windows. You know, one that still has mainstream support. `mklink` exists since Windows Vista (mostly because NTFS didn't gain symlink capabilities before that).

Comment: ntfs changed from xp to vista? good to know. and well, most companies still use windows xp, not my reasoning, i prefer linux anyway :P

Comment: NTFS features changed with every major Windows version so far. Vista brought transactions and symlinks, Windows 2000 added reparse points, quotas, sparse files and more, etc.

Comment: @knittl if you want links in XP, use fsutil.

Comment: `mklink 2 1`: `You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.` Really...

Comment: @levantpied: This question was about hardlinks, which you can create as a normal user. On Windows 10: »For users who have Developer Mode enabled, the mklink command will now successfully create a symlink if the user is not running as an administrator.«

Comment: @Joey To clarify - I +1ed this one, the answer itself was good + useful for me. The "Really..." part was just for my disbelief that you need admin permissions to create symlinks...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) to easily do what you want

Answer (score 1):

```
fsutil hardlink create new_file old_file_name
```

You will need to run this from an elevated command prompt.